# How do I make an image push up another image within a <marquee> tag

Tags: html, css, marquee

I am just starting HTML and some basic CSS, Im here trying to make a Rocketship push up another image with some simple  tags,

Ive tried everything.

I have right now,

```
<div align="center" >
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">
<img class="ImageOne" src="images.png">
<img class="ImageTwo" src="falcon9-render.png">
</div>
</marquee>
```

I have tried some CSS which is in my stylesheet.css right now, and here is that code.

```
image {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.imageOne {
    z-index: 0;
}
.imageTwo {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and at this point, i dont even know if im using z-index in the right context. If its hard to see my vision, Im bascially trying to push and image up with another image under it. or create that kind of visual, i dont know if i have to edit the pixel and align them up.  The rocket seems to be being in the center but the src="images.png" is on the side but its under the  tag...

Sorry if this is dumb and simple but I couldnt find anything.

As Requested in comments; https://jsfiddle.net/7ohrpk42/

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you have so far and also add an image if you can of what you want to achieve

Comment: JFYI, your `div` and `marquee` tags are closing in an incorrect order. And the CSS entry for div `image` should probably be `img`.

Comment: @Pixelomo here it is https://jsfiddle.net/7ohrpk42/

Comment: If i have understood you correctly then i think you should make your image as block element coz image is inline element https://jsfiddle.net/e79w612o/

Comment: Yess this works like the other persons answer but i just dont understand why it is ignoring the align="center" statement...? like its all to the left @Vitorinofernandes

Comment: basically a block element takes up full width so you can center a block element by giving `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` 
text-align center will only work for a `inline` or `inline-block` element
https://jsfiddle.net/e79w612o/1/

Comment: @AriaGhasemi so you need to align not the div but the images to center. the div is already aligned. more so, if they are placed as blocks they would inherit the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Solution:

```css
img {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML!>
  <html>

  <body bgcolor=“#add8e6”>
    <title>The Most Best Worst Websites</title>
    <div align="center">
      <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">
        <img class="ImageOne" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g2ZJTkHk/images.png">
        <img class="ImageTwo" src="https://i.postimg.cc/mD5W47bx/falcon9-render.png">
      </marquee>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Your questions a little unclear without a jsFiddle, but I think you are trying to do something like this:

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.imageOne {
  margin: none;
}

.imageTwo {
  margin: none;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up">
    <img class="ImageOne" src="https://place-hold.it/20x30">
    <br>
    <img class="ImageTwo" src="https://place-hold.it/20x30">
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: here is a JsFiddle if it helps now, I tried the code but it seems to be all stuck to the left, is there a way to center it? the div="center" didnt work https://jsfiddle.net/7ohrpk42/

Comment: Check the updated solution. _And you got strong language/content there._

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can be done by setting the "f&*k you" image as the background of the marquee and background size to 'cover'. Like this:

```
marquee{
  background: url('https://i.postimg.cc/g2ZJTkHk/images.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0vd79j2h/

Answer (score 0):

## [`<marquee>` is Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

It is strongly recommended that `<marquee>` be avoided -- it's deprecated and on its way to becoming obsolete. We can still customize HTML elements to behave and appear as a `<marquee>` with [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) (or even with JavaScript/jQuery although it wouldn't be as efficient as CSS). The following demo uses CSS animation only, and the only images are actually fonts (like [emoticons](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/picto))

---

### Demo

```css
.marquee {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50vh;
  /* Required on Parent */
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 400 15vh/1.5 Consolas;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.marquee b,
.marquee i {
  /* Required on Child*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  /* Infinite Loops */
  animation: climb 2s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /* Set to 0s in order to have a point of reference */
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.marquee i {
  animation: fall 2s linear infinite;
}


/* Required for complex CSS animation */


/* Bottom to top / Left to right */

@keyframes climb {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-200%, 300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(300%, -300%);
  }
}


/* Top to bottom / Right to left */

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translate(200%, -20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-300%, 300%);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class='marquee fall'>
  <i></i><em>✨</em>
</header>

<header class='marquee climb'>
  <b></b><em></em>
</header>
```

Comment: this doesn’t seem as efficient since there’s more code and I’m just a beginner and barely have any knowledge. I’ll try that code as well. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Of course there's more code, it's replacing the behavior of a special element that will be obsolete. Did you read the article at the link I provided or do you know what deprecated or obsolete mean? Plus there are more factors that attribute to efficiency than just the amount of code.